# Small white space going down side of website

Tags: html, css

For this website I'm building, I have recently ran into a small strip of white going down the right side. I have rolled my changes back to when I know there wasn't that line, and it is still there. I am trying to find the css that is pushing it over, but I can't. And the only element that is encroaching into that whitespace is my navbar, but it's width is 100%, so it shouldn't extend the viewport.

How can I find the CSS rule that is forcing that whitespace?

The website is: https://meganandadam2018.com

Comment: I'd need to see your code, but if I had to guess it's probably caused by a `margin` or `margin-right` on one of the elements.

Comment: I'm not seeing it on Chrome/Mac - is it possible you fixed it with the roll-back and are just seeing a cached version?

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4m3f0bqc/7/) is a fiddle that shows a white bar on the side.

Comment: margin-right:4px is causing the whitespace. You probably want to use padding-right: 4px instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove your margin on this class. If you already have 100% width, setting more margin will make the div expand:

```
.home-sec-3 #radio-button-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px; // here is the problem, set right and left to 0
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it!! And to keep my whitespace, I'm changing margin to padding!!

Comment: @AdamMcGurk This is correct, to elaborate a bit more... with `box-sizing: border-box` border and padding are calculated into width, but margin is not. So your `width: 100%;` was actually 100% + 10px margin-left + 10px margin-right causing an overflow.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove `height: 100%` from body and html and add `overflow-x: hidden;`